# Using ng-if on a parent ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting at front-end development and there´s something that I don't know if it's possible to do using AngularJS and ng-repeat.

I have an array with 3 levels of data so the first ng-repeat lists the level 1, inside it there's another ng-repeat that lists the level 2 anda at last another one that lists level 3. Something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item-1 in level-1">
     <div ng-repeat="item-2 in level-2">
         <div ng-repeat="item-3 in level-3">
             {{item-3.name}} : {{item-3.valid}}
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

What I wan't to know if it´s possible to use the ng-if directive on the first level repeat but with a condition of the tird level repeat, something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item-1 in level-1" ng-if="item-3.valid == true">
     <div ng-repeat="item-2 in level-2">
         <div ng-repeat="item-3 in level-3">
             {{item-3.name}} : {{item-3.valid}}
         </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Identifiers with hyphens (`-`) in them are invalid. E.g. `level-1` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

What about moving this logic to the controller managing this HTML. For example something like:

```
$scope.toBeDisplayedItems = [..];
$scope.level1 = [..];
$scope.level2 = [..];
$scope.level3 = [..];
for (var item1 in $scope.level1) {
  for (var item2 in $scope.level2) {
     for (var item3 in $scope.level3) {
       // do something with $scope.level1[item1] $scope.level2[item2] $scope.level3[item3] 
       // then fill the candidate array to be used in the HTML
       $scope.toBeDisplayedItems.push(....);
     }
  }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in toBeDisplayedItems">
     {{item.name}} : {{item.valid}}
</div>
```

By the way I didn't get your check on item-3 in top level of first loop, is that actually working? 
Anyway I answered you on the way it's done and not on the how.